# Security of Objective C Post Method (iOS) over HTTPS

Tags: xcode, ios7

I am using the following code to post to a server from Objective C under iOS 7.  It should be mentioned that this post IS over SSL.

```
NSString *externalURL = @"https://someurl";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:externalURL]];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *postDataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth=%s&id=%@&title=%@&name=%@&msg=%@&sec=%@&img=%@&code=%@",AUTH_CODE,channelID,channelTitle,screenName,msg,secName,imgKey,passCode];

NSData *requestBodyData = [postDataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestBodyData];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
[postDataTask setTaskDescription:@"postMessage"];

[postDataTask resume];
```

My intention is to use the "auth" you see above to protect the server from acceping a call from another source.  Again, I am tramsitting this over SSL but I am wondering if it is possible for the user to intercept the call before it goes over SSL and potentially see the value sent for "auth"?  If this can be intercepted than the whole notion of using an authorization code like this becomes pretty much useless.

---Update----

As a general update for anyone coming across this thread, I have decided to approach this problem as follows knowing unfortunately there are still possible holes.

I am using the values from the data I am sending the service, combined with a secret key known to my app and the server, to create a SHA-256 hash.  I send this hash along with the data to the server.  The server than also computes the hash and if the two are equal the request is processed.  I've used this process elsewhere to verify passwords.  The obvious hole here is that if someone gets a hold of my secret code the jig is up.  This is far more likely to occur on the client than the server.  They would need to disassemble the app which would expose the code.  So not perfect but the best I have for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's hard to give a useful answer to security questions until you state a threat model. Without knowing what or who you are attempting to protect against there's no way to evaluate what protection, if any, a given scheme provides.

Is your intent is to keep a shared secret (`AUTH_CODE`) which is known to the server and client apps but not to the users of those apps who control the devices they run on? If so then this is a pointless exercise. As the owner of my device I can man-in-the-middle my own SSL connections with a trusted cert and read the content of their requests and responses, I can observe messages sent to `NSURLSession` and other classes, and I can dig through installed apps to identify constants and other resources. This sort of approach will be broken the moment someone finds it useful to do so.

If your intent is to prohibit third parties from connecting to your service then such an approach is still likely to fail. Without the ability to inspect a request they may be unable to reconstruct this token however all they have to do is download the app to promote themselves into the case above. They are then free to extract this token and use it in their own clients. Additionally if this is a globally shared secret then it only needs to be compromised once by one user and it can then be shared with anyone interested in connecting to your server. Once again I suspect such an approach will last only until someone finds it useful to break.

In fact I will argue that there is nothing you can do to successfully guard against the first case if your users are determined to use their own client to connect to your system. No matter how convoluted you make the system you have to hand it over to the end users and at that point they are free to reverse engineer it.

There are however two things you can do which might mitigate whatever threat you are concerned about.

1. Establish per-user sessions rather than global shared secrets. This could mean requiring a set of log-in credentials (possibly via a third party platform) or verifying a receipt with a unique transaction id proving a purchase of the app. Such credentials can still be shared by many users but at least you can then act on that shared account.
2. Accept that you cannot trust clients to be well behaved and design your back-end system to account for that.

What threat do you actually face and why do you think is it important that you be able to identify "valid" clients?

Comment: Thank you for the very thoughtful answer.  My intention is to prevent anyone from calling my web service.  It would therefore be possible for a user, if they got the auth code, to call the web service and change data as a result.  The data could be "valid" data from a web service point of view, but not in terms of what I want a person to be able to submit.  You were correct that my intention was to use an auth code known only to my app and the server.  The server would verify the code before accepting the post.  As I was afraid of, this approach now seems worthless.

Comment: Yup, sorry. Don't trust clients. For whatever it's worth I recommend having the service validate any data from a client (and then sanitize it again on the way out but that's a different concern). Even that may not be enough if you're worried about users faking games with perfect high scores or other such issues.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it isn't enough.  This isn't about bad data which i can easily deal with.  It's about preventing state changes that aren't within my control.